# How to draw 2 readily available Figure objects alongside

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's see a contrived example of 2 `matplotlib.pyplot` functions returning a plot, which then may be accessed through `plt.gcf()` or `plt.gca()` methods:

```
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 11)
y = x
y_2 = x * x

plt.plot(x,y)
fig_1 = plt.gcf()
ax_1 = plt.gca()
#plt.close()

plt.plot(x,y_2)
fig_2 = plt.gcf()
ax_2 = plt.gca()
#plt.close()
```

How would I nicely draw `fig_1` and `fig_2` objects alongside through e.g. `plt.subplots(1,2)` (given `x`, `y`, `y_2` are not accessable)

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't allow to "move" subplots from one figure  to another. Also, when you call `plt.close()`, you loose all access to the created figure.  `fig_1` is a handle to access information, it does not contain a copy of that information. So, your figures aren't readily available at all. If you need a subplot afterwards, you should store the necessary data and make a function to create it. Usually such function gets an `ax` as parameter.

Comment: @JohanC Will it change anything if there were no `plt.close()` command after any of the plots?

Comment: You'll need to create a new figure (`fig_2 = plt.figure(...)` or even better: `fig_2, ax_2 = plt.subplots(...)`).  The first figure would be created automatically, although in this case it would be recommended to also create it explicitly. Depending on the environment where you're running things, you should be able to *access* the plots, but you still wouldn't be able to move around subplots from one figure to another.

Comment: I can access (and print to the output) fig_1 and fig_2. I can even edit them, The question is how to put them one next to the other in a single plot.

Comment: You can't put them next to each other after they have been created.  You need to create them directly inside the desired subplot, as shown by @Vagner's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `add_subplot` method of the Figure object to draw the two plots alongside.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 11)
y = x
y_2 = x * x    

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2) # create a figure with subplots
axs[0].plot(x, y) # first figure 
axs[1].plot(x, y_2) # second figure
plt.show()
```

if no given given x, y, y_2:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axs[0].plot(x, y)
axs[1].plot(x, y_2)
plt.show()
```

[image]